# When is right to kill $r^l$ and/or $r^{(-l-1)}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, approximation, frobenius-method

When we solve the Laplace equation in spherical polar coordinate, we get the radial part whose solution is:

$$R=Ar^l+Br^{-(l+1)}$$

Now, some solutions keep this two terms, but when we derive the Hydrogen Atom Wave Equation, we usually kill $Br^{-(l+1)}$ since $l+1$ is not well Normalized so we kill it. The interesting part is, this solution turns out to predict the behavior of Hydrogen atom to a high degree of accuracy! Math is truly great! :)

Now, if its not well normalized why do some DE solutions keep it?

Or in a more general way, what is the right circumstance to keep or kill either $r^l$ or $r^{-(l+1)}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This all depends on the desired behaviour of the solution as $r \to 0$. In physical applications, it is often reasonable to demand that the solution you're looking for is *bounded* as $r \to 0$. In your case, the differential equation gives two linearly independent solutions, which is equivalent to the fact that you can choose $A$ and $B$ 'freely'. That is, this is the moment when you're going to apply the given *boundary conditions*. Usually, these conditions give the value of the solution at a certain point; however, boundary conditions may also come in the form of a limit -- in your case, the condition that the limit of the solution for $r \to 0$ actually exists.

In other problems, such a 'limit condition' may take other forms. For example, it may very well possible that the boundary condition for a certain solution $\phi$ is
\begin{equation}
 \lim_{r \to 0} r^2 \phi(r) \quad \text{exists}.
\end{equation}
In your case, this condition is satisfied for any choice of $A$; it is also satisfied for any choice of $B$ as long as $l \leq 1$. So, to conclude: the choice of 'free' constants $A$ and $B$ depends on the boundary conditions, which are very much related to the physical interpretation of the problem at hand.

Comment: Ok, I get it now, I guess. So if a function exist at r=0 and l=0, we should not have 0 at the denominator, so if we choose $r^{-(l+1)}$ we would have an indefinite term due to $0^{0-1}=\frac{1}{0}$, which should not be. Did I get it right?

Comment: That's the idea, yes.