# Is $e^{-r/2}$ equivalent to $r^{-(l+1)}$ in the radial solution of Laplace equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, approximation, frobenius-method

When we solve the Laplace equation for Hydrogen Wave Equation at large r, we obtain the expression below to account for the behavior of the wave at very very large $r$

$$R=e^{-(r/2)}$$

At very small $r$ we will have a general solution for the radial equation to be

$$R=Ar^l+Br^{-(l+1)}$$

Well interestingly, when I am learning DE solution for Laplace, the second part in the equation above usually takes charge of very large $r$. If that is the case, could $Br^{-(l+1)}$ be equivalent to $e^{-(r/2)}$? If not, when would be the best case to use one from the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for the radial part of the Schroedinger equation is:$$
R_{n,l}(r)=\rho^lL_{n,l}(\rho)e^{-\rho/2}
$$
where $\rho \propto r$ and $L_{n,l}$ is a Laguerre polynomial.

This equation is dominated by the exponential term for large $r$ but as $r$ aproaches $0$ it is the polynomial term that dominates the expression.

That is why you have different approximations for the wave equation.

Now, it is not easy to tell when you have to use one or another of the two expressions. What you can do is to verify that the exponential factor is little enough so that you can assume it is almost $1$: $$
e^{-\rho/2} \gt(1-\epsilon) \iff \rho/2\lt\epsilon \iff r \lt \frac{2\epsilon}{\sqrt{-\frac{2m_e}{\hbar^2}E}} 
$$
Take $\epsilon=.1$ or less and you will know if the polynomial approxiamtion is yet valid.

Comment: I think I get it now, in Hydrogen atom, the Electron Wave should decrease rapidly since it is bound to $~r$ by the very strong force of attraction between electron and proton, thus the use of exponential $e^{-\rho/2}$ - which interestingly naturally comes out of the equations, nice huh. 


While in Laplace Equation involving electric potential of sphere only, the potential is not bound to anything other than its boundary at r->infinity, so its decays at bit slower, thus we use only polynomial $r^{-(l+1)}$.

Comment: I think that when you approximate the solution for small $r$ you have always to put $B=0$ in the equation to avoid that the solution is singular for $r=0$. You can find a similar discussion [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1629145/288459)